# is it possible to cancel all NSURLConnection being processed?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

i have N number of `NSURLConnection` running behind, the thing is that i want cancel all the `NSURLConnection` together. i know we can cancel the `NSURLConnection` one by one

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `NSOperationQueue` by add each connection as an `NSOperation`. When you want to stop all the connections, you can kill the queue with the `cancelAllOperations` method.

Comment: i was using  `ASIHTTPRequest` so i did like this `[[ASIHTTPRequest sharedQueue] cancelAllOperations];` problem solved :)

Answer (score 4):

You could store them all in an `NSArray`, and then iterate over the array cancelling each one.

Comment: can't we access the running connections directly? so we can cancel it